# Any reason why I shouldn't use "between X and Y" on a varchar field in SQL to return a number?

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, between

I've got an indexed (but not unique) varchar field of Employee IDs in a table, and in a query I need to return rows that are `exactly 4 numerical characters` but also over 1000.

I've found various questions on here about using validation methods to check that the field contains 0-9 characters, or doesn't contain a-z characters etc, but these are unrelated to this question.

**Background:**

I've got a table with various values, sample set as follows:

```
EmployeeID
----------
6745
EMP1
EMP2
1874
LTST
5694
0014
```

What I would like to do is return all values *except* `EMP1`, `EMP2`, `LTST` and `0014`.

My question is, are there any reasons why I *shouldn't* use a Where clause like `where EmployeeID between '1000' and '9999'`? Reason for this being employeeid is a varchar column

If I can do this, should I also Order By employee ID, or does this not matter?

Comment: return all values except EMP1, EMP2, LTST and 0014. What is the reason for this ?.you can do a between as well like you said in question.What  is the issue you are facing

Comment: @TheGameiswar my question is whether there are reasons that I shouldn't use 'between' in this way, ie could it return unexpected results that aren't numeric as we read them

Answer (score 2):

I believe "0014" would be left out of the where clause `between '1000' and '9999'`, so that's a reason.  Perhaps `between '0000' and '9999'` would suit your purposes better.  Just remember that you're still sorting based on text.  If you have any entries like "1_99", this would also show up in your query results with your given between clause.

If you're looking to only return 4-character numbers excluding leading zeroes, then the following addition should suffice:

```
WHERE EmployeeID BETWEEN '1000' AND '9999' AND TRY_CAST(EmployeeID As int) IS NOT NULL
```

...or, more intuitively:

```
WHERE TRY_CAST(EmployeeID As int) BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999
```

Comment: Yes, I want `0014` to be left out. in this case, I want only varchar values that are actually numeric, and are actually 4 characters, excluding any leading zeros. It's the values like `1_99` that I would be worried about

Answer (score 1):

Run the following code as an example and you'll see that SQL Server doesn't treat `INT` the same as integers stored as `VARCHAR`:

```
WITH    IntsAsVars
AS      (
        SELECT  var = '1000',
                int = 1000
        UNION   ALL 
        SELECT  var = '100',
                int = 100
        UNION   ALL 
        SELECT  var = '9999',
                int = 999
        UNION   ALL 
        SELECT  var = '99',
                int = 99
        UNION   ALL 
        SELECT  var = '750',
                int = 750
        UNION   ALL 
        SELECT  var = '10',
                int = 10
        UNION   ALL 
        SELECT  var = '2',
                int = 2
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    IntsAsVars
--WHERE var BETWEEN '2' AND '750'   
/* should return 2, 10, 99, 100 & 750 if it works like INT
   but does it? */
ORDER   BY
        --var ASC,  
        int ASC;
```

Running it without the where clause gets the following so SQL Server doesn't consider the other records to be between 2 and 750 when they are stored as varchar.:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My scenario wouldn't see this issue because because I'm dealing with fixed length characters as well.

Comment: That's fair enough but does that stop values like '0001'? '0011'? etc?

Answer (score 1):

If your real data is exactly as the sample data in regard of the non-numeric values beginning with a letter, you could use your query to achieve the desired result.

However be aware of of the sort order of the data. If you have got an EmployeeId of `1ABC` it will be included in the data returned by `WHERE EmployeeID BETWEEN '1000' AND '9999'`!

Your approach is **not** suitable to filter out non-numeric values!

An additional `ORDER BY` affects the order of the results only, it has no effect on the evaluation of the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the simplest way is to use like:

```
select * from yourtable
where EmployeeID like '[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have this input:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #test

CREATE TABLE #test
(
    EmployeeID VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_test_EmployeeID ON #test(EmployeeID)

INSERT INTO #test
VALUES 
('6745'),
('EMP1'),
('EMP2'),
('1874'),
('LTST'),
('5694'),
('1000'),
('9999'),
('10L'),
('187'),
('9X9'),
('7est'),
('1ok'),
('0_o'),
('0014');
```

Your statement would also return '1ok','187', '10L' and so on.
Since you mentioned that your employeeID has a fixed length, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #test
WHERE EmployeeID LIKE '[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```